# How to update column coming from TOP 1 of another table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have 2 tables:

- `City` table - columns `CityID`, `Name`, `Period`
- `Assets` table - columns `AssetID`, `Name`

I have to update the `Period` column of the `City` table with `AssetID` of the `Assets` table matching with the top 1 where `City.Name=Assets.Name`. The `Assets` table have identical names for different assets.

Example `Assets` table:

```
AssetID  Name
1        Asset1
2        Asset1
3        Asset2
4        Asset2
```

How can I do this? I tried with different queries but I am not able to get it.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

```
UPDATE City
SET Period = a.AssetID
FROM (SELECT TOP 1 AssetID, Name FROM Assets ORDER BY AssetID ASC) AS a
WHERE City.Name = a.Name;
```

Comment: this will only update the city that matches the top 1 asset.  It will not update all cities with matching assets.  The where clause has no effect on the subquery

Comment: @nuander: I agree, the code only updates the 1st city.  I have provided a working solution.

Answer (score 5):

This should work:

```
update City
set Period = (
    select top 1 a.AssetID
    from Assets a
    where City.Name = a.Name
    order by a.AssetId asc)
```

Sample code to test:

```
create table #City (CityId varchar(20), [Name] varchar(20), Period varchar(20))
create table #Assets (AssetId varchar(20), [Name] varchar(20))

insert into #City values (1, 'Asset1', null)
insert into #City values (2, 'Asset2', null)
insert into #City values (3, 'Asset3', null)

insert into #Assets values (1, 'Asset1')
insert into #Assets values (2, 'Asset1')
insert into #Assets values (3, 'Asset1')
insert into #Assets values (4, 'Asset2')
insert into #Assets values (5, 'Asset2')
insert into #Assets values (6, 'Asset3')
insert into #Assets values (7, 'Asset3')

select * from #City
select * from #Assets

update #City
set Period = (
    select top 1 a.AssetID
    from #Assets a
    where #City.Name = a.Name
    order by a.AssetId asc)

select * from #City

drop table #City
drop table #Assets
```