# SQL Update with need to order in subquery

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012, sql-update, sql-order-by

Yes, SQL `UPDATE` can be used with `order by` in a `SELECT`-subquery.

Anybody out there who has a workaround for following issue:

From time to time a program generates data errors in `TABLE1`  (we are not owner of that code but need to use the program...)

We use a trigger that protocols all changes to an `AUDIT` table.

We can find the error situation (and the correct old value) with following select:

```
select top 1 audit.OldValue 
     from TABLE1
     left join AUDIT on AUDIT.Table1_ID = TABLE1.ID
where <...some conditions...>
   order by AUDIT.UpdateDate desc
```

As there are several changes logged, we only need the LAST change (`order by updatedate` and then taking `TOP 1`)

We would correct the data error, if we could use the `UPDATE` command like

```
Update TABLE1
set VALUE = 
( select top 1 audit.OldValue
    from TABLE1
    left join AUDIT on AUDIT.Table1_ID = TABLE1.ID
  where <...some conditions...>
    order by AUDIT.UpdateDate desc )
where TABLE1.ID = AUDIT.Table1_ID
```

BUT: you cannot use the `order by` in a subquery...

Comment: Which dbms are you using?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to update the column coming from top 1 of other table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6952277/how-to-update-the-column-coming-from-top-1-of-other-table)

Comment: We use MS-SQL-Server 2012

Comment: That restriction doesn't seem to make sense. Do you *think* you cannot use `ORDER BY` in a subquery or have you tried it an got an error message saying so?

Comment: Try using a CTE instead of subquery

Comment: SORRY, today morning it is working...

Answer (score 0):

I changed the `UPDATE`-command to:

```
Update TABLE1
set VALUE = CORRECT_VALUES.OldValue
from
( select top 1 audit.OldValue OldValue, AUDIT.Table1_ID Table1_ID
    from TABLE1
    left join AUDIT on AUDIT.Table1_ID = TABLE1.ID
  where <...some conditions...>
    order by AUDIT.UpdateDate desc ) as CORRECT_VALUES
where TABLE1.ID = CORRECT_VALUES.Table1_ID
```

That works fine.

And as this only changes 1 entry (due to TOP 1) we have to use a loop:

```
Declare @i int = 0
Declare @NUMBER int = (select count(*) from 
   (select distinct AUDIT.Table1_ID 
       from TABLE1
       left join AUDIT on AUDIT.Table1_ID = TABLE1.ID
    where <...some conditions...>
   ) )

while @i < @NUMBER
BEGIN
   SET @i = @i + 1
   <... past the whole UPDATE command here ...>
END
```

Works fine for all records that have to be updated.

Be aware of the `distict` as there may be lots of changes for the same ID and you only need to change the record ones.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `top 1` use `ROW_NUMBER()` and keep only rows where it is `=1`

something like:

```
Update t set Value = A.OldValue
FROM Table1 t
inner join (
    select ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY UserCode ORDER BY MEASUREDATE DESC) N, Id Table1_ID, *
    from AUDIT
) a on a.Table1_ID = t.ID
where <...some conditions...>
AND (a.N=1)
```

You will apply all updates to all records with only one update (pay attention to <...some conditions...>)