# How to update column coming from TOP 1 of another table with specific criteria

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I want to update a table with matching criteria from another table. Another table has multiple records, so just want the top 1 of matched key. This is what I have tried so far:

```
 UPDATE checkList 
 SET checkList.Answer = A.Answer,
    checkList.Response = A.Response,
    checkList.ANmbr = A.DisplayOrder
 FROM checkList  INNER JOIN  (SELECT TOP 1 QuestID, Answer, Response, DisplayOrder FROM TabAnswers WHERE QuestID = checkList.QID ORDER BY DisplayOrder) A
 ON A.QuestID = checkList.QID    
 WHERE checkList.auditid='158478' and checkList.Qtype = '0'
```

It is not picking the correct data from TabAnswers table. TabAnswers has multiple answers for a given question and just need the 1st one to be populated in checkList. 
I found this answer but it pick the first from the table rather than matching crietria
[How to update column coming from TOP 1 of another table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6952277/how-to-update-column-coming-from-top-1-of-another-table)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're referencing a column from a outside of the subquery, you need to use CROSS APPLY instead of INNER JOIN (or OUTER APPLY instead of LEFT OUTER JOIN).

It's also important to always qualify your columns inside a subquery.

```
UPDATE c 
 SET c.Answer = A.Answer,
     c.Response = A.Response,
     c.ANmbr = A.DisplayOrder
 FROM checkList  c
 CROSS APPLY (SELECT TOP 1 ta.QuestID, ta.Answer, ta.Response, ta.DisplayOrder FROM TabAnswers ta WHERE ta.QuestID = c.QID ORDER BY DisplayOrder) A
 WHERE c.auditid='158478' and c.Qtype = '0'
```